# Laravel 5.6 Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::createToken does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to create API authentication using Passport but I can not seem to create a token when a user is being registered using **createToken**().

I have already checked I have included HasApiTokens but still gives same error.

**ERROR**

> Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::createToken does not exist

**App\User**

```
namespace App;

use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
          'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

**SignupController**

```
**public function userLogin(Request $request) 
{
    $email = $request->email;
    $password = $request->password;

    $user = User::where('email' , $email)->where( 'password' , $password);
    if($user)
    {
        $token = $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
        $arr = array('token' => $token, 'status' => 'isTrue', 'userId' => $data[0]->id);
        //return response()->json($arr , 200);
    }**
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fetch the user. Currently $user is the QueryBuilder, not the user object.

`User::where('email', $email)->where('password', $password)->first();`

Comment: Thanks that worked! Just another thing, it seems that I can not check a hashed password in the db with that statement, unless I use the hashed password, how do I do Hash::check() inside that statement...?

Comment: Remove the second where, so your query looks like this `User::where('email', $email)->first();`, then refactor your condition to something like the following `if ($user && Hash::check($password, $user->password))`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the methods like `get()` or `first()` or 'firstOrFail()' to get the database result. all the `where` chains just return the `QueryBuilder`'s object. Second thing is that you won't be saving the password as plain text (if you are saving so then please change it and hashed it before saving). For your case, it would become:

```
$user = User::where('email' , $email)->where( 'password' , $password)->first();
```

In the scenario of hashed password:

```
$user = User::where('email' , $email)->first();
if(Hash::check(optional($user)->password, $request->password)) {
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the

```
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable {

use HasApiTokens,
    Notifiable;
```

trait to your User model.